# popup not closing

Tags: jquery, popup

I am returning an array to the parent from my popup. It all works fine but the popup doesn't close. I even tried window.close

```
function btnClick() 
{
    var myVal = $("input#hdnName").val();
    var myVal1 = $("input#hid").val();
    var myarray = new Array(myVal, myVal1);       
    window.parent.closeDialog(myarray);
    window.close();
        }
```

Comment: where are you creating this *elusive* popup?

Comment: The user is typically the one who closes an `alert`.

Comment: this is a jquery modal dialogue from parent window and loads another aspx page in iframe. I am able to send and return the values back and forth and rest all but popup doesn't close :(

Comment: Alert is only for checking the return data ,sry if that confused anyone. but i am trying to close the popup on button click and this whole is functio. am not talking of alert window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By security reasons, browsers only accepts `window.close()` if that window was opened by a `window.open()` *on the same context*.

In your case, I think the problem is that the `window.close()` is called by the `iframe` but it isn't in the same context that opened the popup.

You can try:

- A popup without the `iframe` inside.
- Or better, don't use popups. Use a div floating over your main page, displaying the `iframe` inside. In fact, there are many jQuery plugins that can do it.